# How to copy back backedup games & profile from usb onto xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360

I was experiencing on system settings with my xbox 360. I plugged in a 16 Gb usb drive , went to storage and pressed Y, i was prompted with options but i chose copy.. configure. I moved all games and profiles to the usb drive. Is it possible to copy all the items back?

Comment: Choosing "copy" usually doesn't remove the files from the source. Meaning that your files should still be on the hard drive.

Comment: I'm wondering if your question has already been answered. If so could you please accept the answer so that other people with the same question can see that there is an accepted answer available?

Answer (score 2):

If what you are saying is that you moved all games and profiles from your Xbox 360 towards your USB-drive then yes, they can be copied or moved back.

[Follow these steps to do so:](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-setup/manage-games-data#e2421d9b8cf5491c91391cd98cc37dec)

> Copy, move, or delete individual items
>
> 1. From Xbox Home, go to **settings**, and then select **System**.
> 2. Select **Storage**.
> 3. Select the storage device that contains the content you want
>      to copy, move, or delete:
>
>    - **Hard Drive**: Your console’s hard drive.
>    - **Cloud Saved Games**: Storage space on our Xbox Live servers. For more
>        information, see [Store your saved games in the cloud](https://support.xbox.com/xbox-live/game-saves-in-the-cloud/cloud-save-games).
>    - **USB Storage Device**: A USB storage device, such as a USB flash drive plugged into your console. To learn more about USB flash drives, see [USB flash drive support for Xbox 360](https://support.xbox.com/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive).
>    - **Memory Unit**: A memory unit plugged into your original Xbox 360 console.
> 4. Select the type of content that you want to copy, move, or delete:
>
>    - Games and Apps
>        **Notes**
>
>      - It's okay to copy and move saved games from one Xbox 360 console to
>          another. You don't have to repurchase the game or reload it onto your
>          second console.
>      - For help with PC game problems, see [Troubleshoot
>          performance and stability issues in PC games](https://support.xbox.com/xbox-on-other-devices/windows/troubleshooting-performance).
>    - Gamer profiles
>        **Note** To make changes to your profile, see [How to view and edit your gamer
>        profile in Games for Windows Live](https://support.xbox.com/my-account/manage-account/edit-games-for-windows-live-profile).
>    - Demos
>    - Videos
>    - Themes
>    - Gamer Pictures
>    - Avatar Items
>    - System Items
>    - Music
> 5. Within the content type that you selected, click to select the item
>      that you want to copy, move, or delete. To move multiple items at
>      once, see [Copy or move multiple items using the Transfer Content
>      option](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-setup/manage-games-data#copy).
> 6. Select **Copy**, **Move**, or **Delete**.
>
>    - **If you're copying or moving content**: Select the storage device that you want to copy or move the item or items to.
>        **Note** After you've copied or moved the content from your console to a storage device, it's okay to repeat this step but instead select **Delete** to delete the content.
>    - **If you're deleting content**: Click **Yes** to confirm the deletion.